# JavaScript string method localeCompare() accepts 'undefined' and refuse 'null' as a 'locale' param

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I found some approach to sort string in natural way

```
const rows = ['37-SK', '4-ML', '41-NP', '2-YZ', '21', '26-BF'];
console.log(rows.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' })));
```

it outputs following:

```
0: "2-YZ"
1: "4-ML"
2: "21"
3: "26-BF"
4: "37-SK"
5: "41-NP"
length: 6
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

but when i replace undefined with null

```
console.log(rows.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, null, { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' })));
```

it outputs:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at String.localeCompare (<anonymous>)
    at natSort.js:2:35
    at Array.sort (<anonymous>)
    at natSort.js:2:18
```

Why?

Comment: Additionally: empty object {} - behave correctly, empty string '' - make invocation throw an exception same as invocation with null.

Comment: Going down the rabbit hole you end at https://tc39.es/ecma402/#sec-canonicalizelocalelist

Answer (score 0):

It's how the spec is written. If the second argument (the *locales* string) is `undefined`, then it's assumed to be whatever is the system default. If it is anything other than `undefined`, then it must be a string with proper locale information, or else that's an error.

*edit* — as noted in a comment, the *locales* argument can also be an already-initialized locale list object. However, it's still true that `undefined` will work, while `null` will not.

Comment: Nope it can be an object, that's why the error occurs if it were only converted to a string that would be fine (or at least another error).

Comment: @Kaiido well fine, but that's the difference between `undefined` and `null`. But yes it can be an object that's an already-initialized locale list.

Answer (score 0):

`String#localeCompare` [takes three parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#parameters):

| Parameter name | Expected value |
| --- | --- |
| `compareString` | The string against which the `referenceStr` is compared. |
| `locales` and `options` | These arguments customize the behavior of the function and let applications specify the language whose formatting conventions should be used. In implementations which ignore the `locales` and `options` arguments, the locale used and the form of the string returned are entirely implementation-dependent. See the [Intl.Collator() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator/Collator) for details on these parameters and how to use them. |

When you pass a value for the `locales` parameter, it's passed to the `Intl.Collator` constructor listed above whose [documentation is available here](https://tc39.es/ecma402/#sec-the-intl-collator-constructor). The steps taken to construct an `Intl.Collator` include:

> 6. Return ? [InitializeCollator](https://tc39.es/ecma402/#sec-initializecollator)(`collator`, `locales`, `options`).

[The documentation for `InitializeCollator`](https://tc39.es/ecma402/#sec-initializecollator) includes the step:

> 1. Let `requestedLocales` be ? [CanonicalizeLocaleList](https://tc39.es/ecma402/#sec-canonicalizelocalelist)(`locales`).

Here's the actual answer, then. [The documentation for `CanonicalizeLocaleList`](https://tc39.es/ecma402/#sec-canonicalizelocalelist) includes the steps for handling the value you passed to `locales` all the way back in `String#localeCompare`:

1. If `locales` is `undefined`, then
   a. Return a new empty [`List`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-list-and-record-specification-type).
2. [...]
3. If [Type](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(`locales`) is `String` or [Type](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(`locales`) is `Object` and `locales` has an `[[InitializedLocale]]` internal slot, then
   a. Let `O` be ! [CreateArrayFromList](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-createarrayfromlist)(« `locales` »).
4. Else
   a. Let `O` be ? [ToObject](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-toobject)(`locales`).
5. [...]
6. [...]
7. [...]
8. [...]

Looking at the [documentation for `ToObject(argument)`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-toobject):

| Argument Type | Result |
| --- | --- |
| Undefined | Throw a `TypeError` exception. |
| **Null** | **Throw a `TypeError` exception.** |
| Boolean | Return a new Boolean object whose [[BooleanData]] internal slot is set to `argument`. See 20.3 for a description of Boolean objects. |
| Number | Return a new Number object whose [[NumberData]] internal slot is set to `argument`. See 21.1 for a description of Number objects. |
| String | Return a new String object whose [[StringData]] internal slot is set to `argument`. See 22.1 for a description of String objects. |
| Symbol | Return a new Symbol object whose [[SymbolData]] internal slot is set to `argument`. See 20.4 for a description of Symbol objects. |
| BigInt | Return a new BigInt object whose [[BigIntData]] internal slot is set to `argument`. See 21.2 for a description of BigInt objects. |
| Object | Return `argument`. |

---

To summarize, if you pass:

### `undefined`

`localeCompare` passes to `Intl.Collator().constructor` which passes to `InitializeCollator` which passes to `CanonicalizeLocaleList` which has an explicit step that returns a new empty `List`.

### `null`

`localeCompare` passes to `Intl.Collator().constructor` which passes to `InitializeCollator` which passes to `CanonicalizeLocaleList` which calls `ToObject` which throws a `TypeError` if it's passed `null`.

---

You asked about two other cases in the comments:

### `{}` (empty object)

`localeCompare` passes to `Intl.Collator().constructor` which passes to `InitializeCollator` which passes to `CanonicalizeLocaleList` which calls `ToObject` which returns the object it is passed.

Note that `CanonicalizeLocaleList` would have handled the object if it had an `[[InitializedLocale]]` internal slot.

### `''` (empty string)

`localeCompare` passes to `Intl.Collator().constructor` which passes to `InitializeCollator` which passes to `CanonicalizeLocaleList` which calls `ToObject` which returns a new `String` object which a length of zero so the rest of `CanonicalizeLocaleList` has no effect and an empty `List` is returned.

I'll admit, I don't know why the empty string case doesn't work. There's probably something deeper in the spec that handles that case.